# Creating multiple popups with this code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to learn jQuery  and popups. I find out this code through Google it works nicely. 
The thing is, this design only allows to create one popup via this javascript. I saw author wrote;

[code](http://yensdesign.com/tutorials/popupjquery/popup.js)

*If you want to create multiple popups without create one division for each popup you need to create a javascript object, then you will be able to create multiple instances of the popup object.*

Update : Below is the code i am using right now. I tried your way but still no joy. Now i can not create and popups with the way i understand from your post.
I take it back to as its below and still have the problem. Appriciate for helping me. I dont understand is it this hard to do thing.

```
/***************************/
//@Author: Adrian "yEnS" Mato Gondelle
//@website: www.yensdesign.com
//@email: yensamg@gmail.com
//@license: Feel free to use it, but keep this credits please!                  
/***************************/


var popupStatus = 0;

function loadPopup()
{
    if(popupStatus == 0)
    {
        $("#backgroundPopup").css({
            "opacity": "0.09"
        });

        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#myPopup").fadeIn("slow");
        popupStatus = 1;
    }
}

function disablePopup()
{
    if(popupStatus == 1)
    {
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#myPopup").fadeOut("slow");
        popupStatus = 0;
    }
}

//centering popup
function centerPopup()
{
    //request data for centering
    var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var popupHeight = $("#myPopup").height();
    var popupWidth = $("#myPopup").width();

    $("#myPopup").css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": windowHeight / 2 - popupHeight / 2,
        "left": windowWidth / 2 - popupWidth / 2
    });

    $("#backgroundPopup").css({
        "height": windowHeight
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#displaypopup").click(function(){
        //centering with css
        centerPopup();
        //load popup
        loadPopup();
    });

    //CLOSING POPUP
    //Click the x event!
    $("#popupClose").click(function(){
        disablePopup();
    });
    //Click out event!
    $("#backgroundPopup").click(function(){
        disablePopup();
    });
    //Press Escape event!
    $(document).keypress(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 27 && popupStatus == 1){
            disablePopup();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: thanks for try to help me friend. I solved all my problem with fancybox js package. take care.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to transform this functions, and more important `popupStatus` to isolated object, so `popupStatus` can be different to many different jQuery objects in web page.

I would looks like:

```
function PopUP(backgroundPopup, popupContact)
{
    /***************************/
    //@Author: Adrian "yEnS" Mato Gondelle
    //@website: www.yensdesign.com
    //@email: yensamg@gmail.com
    //@license: Feel free to use it, but keep this credits please!                  
    /***************************/

    //SETTING UP OUR POPUP
    //0 means disabled; 1 means enabled;
    this.popupStatus = 0;

    //loading popup with jQuery magic!

    //notice $("#backgroundPopup") --> 
    this.loadPopup = function(){
        //loads popup only if it is disabled
        if(popupStatus == 0)
        {
            $(backgroundPopup).css({
                "opacity": "0.7"
            });
            $(backgroundPopup).fadeIn("slow");
            $(popupContact).fadeIn("slow");
            popupStatus = 1;
        }
    }

    //disabling popup with jQuery magic!
    this.disablePopup =  function (){
        //disables popup only if it is enabled
        if(popupStatus == 1)
        {
            $(backgroundPopup).fadeOut("slow");
            $(popupContact).fadeOut("slow");
            popupStatus = 0;
        }
    }

    //centering popup
    this.centerPopup = function (){
        //request data for centering
        var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        var popupHeight = $(popupContact).height();
        var popupWidth = $(popupContact).width();
        //centering
        $(popupContact).css({
            "position": "absolute",
            "top": windowHeight / 2 - popupHeight / 2,
            "left": windowWidth / 2 - popupWidth / 2
        });
        //only need force for IE6
        $(backgroundPopup).css({
            "height": windowHeight
        });
    }
}
```

Notice that you cannot *hard code* `ID` of pop-up element, there need to be different ID for every pop-up. That is why there are parameters in  this function, which is also an object.
So you would use sth like that to create instance of this function-class:

```
//Click the button event!backgroundPopupID
backgroundPopupID = "#backgroundPopup";
popupContactID = "#popupContact";
var popup1 = new PopUP(backgroundPopupID ,popupContactID);

$("#button").click(popup1.centerPopup(),popup1.loadPopup());//not sure if this works
```

I actually don't use JavaScript object very often, so I would likely remove the `popupStatus` and instead of that I would add a class to pop-up so I could check if pop up is enabled or disabled. You can use `$(selector).hasClass(className)` and  `$(selector).addClass( className )`. You should also make every function parametrized with popup selector (just like this function-class in example above).

Answer (score 0):

I spend a few hours to modify the code for this JavaScript, but I give up, and look for an easier solution. I chose [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) very handy and easy to use.

http://www.aobaba.com/_multiplepopup/

and you can download the package from here:
http://www.aobaba.com/_multiplepopup/colorbox_multiplepopup.zip